# Applying conditions on has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm having trouble retrieving some data from a Postgre database with rails 4.1.8

Let's considere two models with a has_many relationship

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

and

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Comments have a state with `approved` or `censured`

I want to write a method in Post model `self.all_comments_approved`

I cannot figure out how to get **only posts with all comments approved**.
I would like to write something like this (not working example) :

```
def sef.all_comments_approved
  joins(:comments).where("ALL(comments.state = 'approved')").references(:comments)
end
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using `joins` with `group` and `having` statement, but relation you would get would be very fragile (you wouldn't be able to query it any further as easily as you wish - `pluck` would destroy it completely etc).

Way around this issue is to split it into two db calls:

```
def self.all_comments_approved
  non_approved_ids = joins(:comments).where.not(comments: {state: 'approved'}).uniq.pluck(:id)
  where.not(id: non_approved_ids)
end
```